# Invoking a private method in subclass from inherited public method

Tags: java, inheritance

I read the following example in a book and its output is correct:

```
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Person().printPerson(); // Person
        new Student().printPerson(); // Person : Line 6
    }
}
class Student extends Person 
{
    private String getInfo() // Line 11
    {
        return "Student";
    }
}
class Person 
{
    private String getInfo() 
    {
        return "Person";
    }
    public void printPerson() 
    {
        System.out.println(getInfo());
    }
}
```

The explanation for the output "Person" instead of "Student" in Line 6 is as follow:
new Student().printPerson() does not invoke the getInfo() method in the Student class, because it is private and can only be invoked from a method in the Student class.

My Question is:

printPerson() method is not private in Person class hence it is inherited in Student class => it is available in Student class.

Why it can't invoke getInfo() method at Line 11 ?
printPerson() and getInfo() are both available in Student class (printPerson() method through inheritance)

Comment: Private methods are not inherited. They do not participate in dynamic dispatch. The `Student.getInfo()` method is entirely separate from the `Person.getInfo()` method, and the former does not override the latter. Additionally, the `Person.printPerson()` method, while it is _inherited_ by `Student`, it is not _overridden_ by `Student`. And which method is invoked is determined at compile-time. In this case, the chosen method is `Person.getInfo()`, because that's the only legal method in context. And that method is invoked "directly" because private methods are not polymorphic.

Comment: This is an important property for encapsulation. If it worked the opposite way with private methods   inherited and overridable in subclasses, then adding a private method to a superclass could change the behaviour of a subclass. This would be undesirable, as private methods are meant to hide implementation details, and are not part of the interface of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use @Override annotation when you want to check if method is allowed to be overridden or not in child classes, in this case you will find that it will throw a compile time error, apart from that, explanation seems pretty clear